# Sharepoint Javascript (_sp) does not run in uploaded file to library for Client Web Part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I uploaded a file (`.htm`) to my sharepoint library. When I click the file, it brings me to a page and runs the script, however the sharepoint javascript does not work. When i type `_spPageContextInfo.userId;` into the console, it errors `not defined`.

When i try typing `_spPageContextInfo.userId;` into the console of the previous window, the sharepoint library, it returns my user id.

Any thoughts on how to get the sharepoint javascript to still run in the uploaded file? I am running sharepoint 2010

When I open up chromes dev tools, I do not see the `_layout` folder with `.js` files in it (I see them when I am at the main sharepoint library page). Perhaps there is a way to link to those? I do not know a lot about webpages, sorry.

EDIT:

I've included

```
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/cui.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.ui.mylinksribbon.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.ui.policy.ribbon.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.ui.rte.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.ribbon.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
```

Now when I go to the console I can successfully type `_spPageLoaded`, but `_spPagecontextInfo` is not an option...

Answer (score 2):

Following is what I have found to be the minimum qualifications for a stand alone page to work with the [JavaScript Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538253(v=office.14).aspx) libraries and other features.

You can edit the page with Notepad, or any text editor, and upload to a document library.
Just be sure to save as *.ASPX*

You still won't be able to use a `form` element. But that can be overcome by using the SP.ClientContext or REST API.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <!-- document information -->
  <head>
    <!-- meta information -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!-- css: sharepoint -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=3TRomkG1g2gMGz4rekMIQg%3D%3D"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css?rev=T%2Bhraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ%3D%3D"/>
  </head>

  <!-- document content -->
  <body>
    <!-- required: SharePoint FormDigest -->
    <form runat="server">
      <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    </form>

    <!-- required: script sources -->
    <!-- script: SharePoint -->
    <script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes"></script>

    <!-- script: local -->
    <script>
      console.log(_spPageContextInfo.userId);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the functionality provided by SharePoint, you'll need to embed your content onto a SharePoint page.

1. Edit a page in SharePoint
2. Add a Content Editor web part to a page
3. Edit the Content Editor web part
4. In the web part properties pane that appears on the right side, find the "Content Link" text field
5. Paste in the URL path to your uploaded `.htm` file (note that it doesn't have to be a .htm or .html file... any valid text file will do)
6. Save the web part properties and stop editing the page

The Content Editor web part will then display your content within the page. Your file should contain a valid HTML fragment, and can contain script tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Thriggle. I tried doing this however I then ran into issues with `hover` and also with `<Form>`. Does that seem normal? I am not sure about the hover, but I read that one can not use <Form> because Sharepoint already uses one.

Comment: Yeah, the `form` issue will be because the whole SharePoint page is already wrapped up in a `<form>` tag, and you can't have nested forms. What kind of CSS hover problems are you running into? One thing to keep in mind is that SharePoint 2010 usually forces Internet Explorer into compatibility mode, so you'll essentially by working with IE 8 in terms of CSS and JavaScript support.

Comment: the `onmouseover="hover_sel_img()"` stops working. I also can no longer scroll down the webpage so I'm not sure where that is.

Comment: If you want to post the contents of your HTM file (either by editing your question or posting a new question), I can take a look and see if anything stands out.

Comment: the `<Form>` part is pretty important to my script so I think i'm going to have to look for other ways to include this on my sharepoint sight. Thanks though for your insight!